# Error in sample. Incorrect number of probabilities

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1)

yrs.in.db.both = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.002, 0.008, 0.01, 0.008, 0.006, 0.04, 0.02,  0.015, 
                   0.008, 0.008, 0.003, 0.03, 0.06, 0.08, 0.085, 0.0898, 0.083, 0.081, 
                   0.024, 0.03, 0.04, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.008, 0.007, 0.005, 0.01, 
                   0.01, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.0067, 0.004, 0.006, 0.0078, 0.01, 0.01, 
                   0.0088, 0.076, 0.004, 0.0035, 0.0046, 0.002, 0.0031, 0.0025, 0.0046, 0.0033, 
                   0.0033)


yrs.in.db      = sample(0.1:5.1, 809, prob = yrs.in.db.both, replace = T)

head(yrs.in.db)

hist(yrs.in.db)
```

I keep getting "

```
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities
```

". There are 51 numbers (from 0.1 to 5.1). I have listed 51 probabilities in the vector yrs.in.db.both. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yrs.in.db      = sample(seq(from=0.1,by=0.1,to=5.1), 809, prob = yrs.in.db.both, replace = T)
```

This is probably what you want. The colon operator ":" counts up in units of one. That is, a:b results into {a,a+1,....,b-1,b}, or if b is smaller than a
{a,a-1,....,b+1,b}. If you need a different step-size, you have to use the seq function.
Just run "0.1:5.1" in the command line, the problem should become obvious to you.